# Symfony 3 translation return “A message inside a trans tag must be a simple text.”

Tags: symfony, twig

```
<body>
    {% trans %}
     <h1>Hello</h1>
    {% endtrans %}
</body>
```

Error

> Twig_Error_Syntax
>
> A message inside a trans tag must be a simple text.

Comment: That's a more complicated piece of HTML text. Just put the `trans` tags around the 'Hello', because if you are going to translate that, you'd also want the HTML markup around it for formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to escape the html from your text. Try that

```
<body>
<h1>{% trans %}Hello{% endtrans %}</h1>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like:

```
<body>
    {% trans %}
     hello.body
    {% endtrans %}
</body>
```

and translate as example

```
hello.body: <h1>Hello</h1>
```

If you want to translate also the html charachter or you need to use in the translated string. Otherwise something like:

```
<body>
      <h1>{% trans %}Hello{% endtrans %}</h1>
 </body>
```